# Excel or Rails, Capitalize first letter, change all caps to capitalized, but respect capitalization mid name

Tags: microsoft-excel, ruby, ruby-on-rails, rails

Given names like below:

**richard should be  Richard**

**RICHARD should be Richard**

**richAnne should be RichAnne**

I'd rather this be done in excel, but my other option is using Rails.

Answer (score 1):

use the =Proper() formula it should do the trick.

It wouldn't work on one of your examples though: **richAnne**

You might want to put a space in there to make it work: **rich Anne**